# how can merged byte string split to normal string

Tags: python, regex, string, byte

There is some data which stored improperly in the program, the original process will be like

```py
a=b'abcd'
b=b'cded'
with open('text.txt','w') as wfp:
    wfp.write(str(a))
    wfp.write(str(b))
```

and sure the output string in text.txt becomes `b'abcd'b'cded'`
how can this perform a reverse operation that split and assign as two variables,
I tried to like this but not working, only return `['','','']`

```py
import re
with open('text.txt','r') as fp:
    content = fp.read()
    re.split("""b'\w+'""",content)
```

Comment: Is that enough? `content.split("'")[1::2]`

Comment: Try `re.split(r"(?:^|')b'", content)`